# Random Number Generator - That Stops

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

I am using Python.

How can I make a code that generates random numbers between 1 and 1000 (inclusive) infinitely until it generates the number 39 and stops?

Here is what I've tried so far, however it has not worked:

```
import random

print(random.randint(1,1000))

if random.randint=39:

break
```

Comment: Learn about loops. `for`, `while` etc

Comment: You should be using `while` as `while random.randint(1, 1000) != 39:`

Comment: You can use `itertools` to build the generator for you. Its kinda dense code... `itertools.takewhile(
        lambda x: x!=39, 
        itertools.starmap(random.randint, itertools.repeat((1, 1000))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import random
while random.randint(1,1000) != 39:
    pass
```

Or (depending on your needs):

```
import random
while True:
    if random.randint(1,1000) == 39:
        break
```

If you want to create **generator** try something like this :

```
import random

def generate_numbers(exact_number):    
    while True:
        n = random.randint(1,1000)
        if n == exact_number:
            break
        yield n

#example usage
for i in generate_numbers(39):
    print(i)
```